# Webview Camera, Audio permission issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

The video calling feature was working perfectly with webview until almost 3 months ago. Recently it's not supporting camera and audio functionality, even browser and application have both of these permissions. I would like to know if it is because of any recent update with webview or Chromium or with anything else, as it was working properly before.

Below is the method used to load the URL:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    getBindingModel().webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    getBindingModel().webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
    getBindingModel().webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return false
        }
    }

    getBindingModel().webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
            getBindingModel().loadingText.text = "$newProgress%"
            getBindingModel().loadingText.visibility =
                if (newProgress > 99) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
            getBindingModel().progress.visibility =
                if (newProgress > 99) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            runOnUiThread { request?.grant(request.resources) }
        }
    }
}
```